# Django - How include() can be used to create plug and play URLs?

Tags: python, django

As mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/),

> the `include()` function allows referencing other URLconfs. Note that the regular expressions for the `include()` function don't have a $ (end-of-string match character) but rather a trailing slash. Whenever Django encounters `include()`, it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the included URLconf for further processing.
>
> The idea behind `include()` is to **make it easy to plug-and-play URLs**. Since polls are in their own URLconf (`polls/URLs.py`), they can be placed under `/polls/`, or under `/fun_polls/`, or under `/content/polls/`, or any other path root, and the app will still work.

---

Need clarification on second point(above) about, *`include()` is to make it easy to plug-and-play URLs*,

For one of the app(`webapp`) in Django project:

```
webapp/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    migrations/
        __init__.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
```

where, root URLconf is pointing to `webapp.urls` as shown below,

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^webapp/', include('webapp.urls')),
]
```

---

[here](https://github.com/shamhub/Web-app/tree/master/2_Django_project) is the complete code

With `webapp` app, How `include()` can be used in creating plug and play URLS?

Comment: @cdarke from `django.conf.urls ` and using it as `url(r'^webapp/', include('webapp.urls')),`

Comment: what does not work? Can you explain? Does it show any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe in a django project, you will register many apps into it, and each will have its own urlconf, at that moment, using the `include()` will make things simple.

You could just add a prefix for each app and using `include()` to combine all into root urlConf.

> Whenever Django encounters include(), it chops off whatever part of
>   the URL matched up to that point and sends the remaining string to the
>   included URLconf for further processing.

The `include()` works by `import_module()`, you could refer to this function at [this](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/urls/__init__.py)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152897/discussion-on-answer-by-guangshengzuo-django-how-include-can-be-used-to-crea).

Answer (score 0):

In Django URLs, `include()` lets you refer to other app's URLconfs.
It basically means something like this

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^webapp/', include('webapp.urls')),
]
```

`webapp.urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.content),
]
```

Now, whenever you will call `/webapp/` it will render the `content` view.

Plug-and-Play basically means URL `/webapp/` is ready to be called. It will return anything that will come under this URL if you have a `view` specified for this `URL`.

Comment: If I just say, `url(r'^webapp/', webapp.urls)`, how is that plug-and-play aspect missing?

Comment: `include()` takes the import path to another URLconf module that should be “included” in this place.
You can also do it without using `include()` by mentioning the namespace for the webapp's urls.